# Filter tibble in R when column names (to be filtered) and values are in vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This might be an esoteric question or use-case, but is there a quick way to `filter` a tibble when the column names and values are inside vectors?

Say I want to filter `mpg` and `hp` in `mtcars`. I could do something like:

```
filter(mtcars, mpg >= 15 & hp >= 100)
```

But instead, say I have several filtering cases -- with the columns to be filtered in one vector and the values in another. (In practice, I might have four or five cases in a larger df.)

```
car_stat <- c('mpg', 'hp')
car_value <- c(15, 100)
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

```
filter(mtcars, car_stat >= car_value)
```

But is there some succinct `dplyr/tidyverse` way to filter with vectors, or am I resigned to using some loop to break it up into separate vectors, each of length one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your variables and values, you can turn those into filtering expressions. Here we use the base R `Map` and `bquote` functions

```
car_stat <- c('mpg', 'hp')
car_value <- c(15, 100)

criteria <- unname(Map(function(c, v) bquote(.(as.name(c))>=.(v)), car_stat, car_value))
criteria
# [[1]]
# mpg >= 15
# 
# [[2]]
# hp >= 100
```

This creates a list of expressions that you want for your filter. Then you can inejct them to `filter` with `!!!`

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, !!!criteria)
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great start. I'm not too familiar with `bquote` and tried to look at some documentation. Let's assume that I have a third vector with sign operators (i.e. `car_signs = c('>=', '<=')`)

How do I incorporate that third variable to include the new signs, assuming that not every expression needs to be evaluated equal to car_value?

I tried: `unname(Map(function(c, v, s) bquote(.(as.name(c)).(as.name(s)).(v)), car_stat, car_value, car_sign))`but this throws some error related to an unexpected symbol?

Comment: I'm not sure how you formatted your `car_sign` values. But you can't insert an infix operation with bquote directly. You need to call it in it's functional form. For example: `x <- as.name("<=");bquote(.(x)(5, 2))` will return `5 <= 2`

Comment: Elegant answer! Sorry for going off-topic, but do you by any chance know any other interesting/elegant examples or use cases of ``bquote``? The R documentation examples, especially the case with ``splice = T``, seem very interesting, would really love to explore it further.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that leverages the `env` parameter of data.table 1.14.9

```
library(data.table)
cars = setDT(copy(mtcars))

do.call(
  fintersect,
  lapply(1:2, \(i) cars[k>=z, env = list(k=car_stat[i], z =car_value[i])])
)
```

Output:

```
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb id
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  2
 3: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  4
 4: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  5
 5: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  6
 6: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 10
 7: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 11
 8: 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 12
 9: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 13
10: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 14
11: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 22
12: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 23
13: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 25
14: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 28
15: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 29
16: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 30
17: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 31
18: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 32
```